# how to test responsive design in all screen resolutions?

Tags: responsive-design, screen-orientation, screen-resolution

I need to test a responsive website based on all screen resolution, as you know for example we can drag FireFox or Chrome browser size by mouse and resize page but **I believe this is not correct way**.

- but please share your idea about it

.
There are also some websites that they provide same facility by checking website in all devices screen, but it's not trustworthy.

> I need to know what is the best way and routine way to check
>   responsive website for all screen devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the developer tool of mozilla firefox, in the top right portion click on the square icon to enable mobile mode.

read for more here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode

Comment: Well, Let me ask you, can we trust on this tool ? I mean it will show exactly based on real device ?

Comment: Yes, its part of mozilla browser.

Comment: Same with chrome, it has a builtin mobile tester mode

Comment: Thanks. so it means the only possible way is chrome and firefox tester mode. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently tried using **browsersync** and it works quite well.

BrowserSync essentially allows you to test your site across a network of devices, and what you do on one device is immediately visible on the others. Your scroll, click, refresh and form actions are mirrored between browsers while you test.

Here's the link: https://www.browsersync.io/

Comment: how about browser window resize ;)